# How do I sort this array of pointers without changing the sort of the original array?

Tags: c

I made this file to work out some confusion I had with pointers and arrays of pointers.  I understand up until the commented out code, and am able to change the order of the values in p_to_pointers without changing p_to_nums.  But I'm having trouble translating it to qsort.

Here is my output:

```
0 p_to_nums: 7 p_to_pointers: 7
1 p_to_nums: 4 p_to_pointers: 4
2 p_to_nums: 4 p_to_pointers: 4
3 p_to_nums: 2 p_to_pointers: 2
4 p_to_nums: 1 p_to_pointers: 1
```

This is the desired output:

```
0 p_to_nums: 4 p_to_pointers: 7
1 p_to_nums: 2 p_to_pointers: 4
2 p_to_nums: 7 p_to_pointers: 4
3 p_to_nums: 4 p_to_pointers: 2
4 p_to_nums: 1 p_to_pointers: 1
```

And my code:

```
int compare_values (const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *int_a = (const int *) a;
    const int *int_b = (const int *) b;

    return (*int_b > *int_a) - (*int_b < *int_a);
}

main() {

    int i;
    int nums[5];
    int *p_to_nums;
    int *p_to_pointers[5];

    nums[0] = 4;
    nums[1] = 2;
    nums[2] = 7;
    nums[3] = 4;
    nums[4] = 1;

    p_to_nums = &nums[0];

  for (i=0; i< 5; i++) {
        p_to_pointers[i] = &p_to_nums[i];
  }

    //p_to_pointers[0] = &p_to_nums[2];
    //p_to_pointers[2] = &p_to_nums[0];

    qsort(*p_to_pointers, 5, sizeof(int), compare_values);

    for (i=0; i< 5; i++) {
        printf("%d p_to_nums: %d p_to_pointers: %u\n", i, (p_to_nums[i]), *p_to_pointers[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `p_to_pointers` values do not point to pointers. In fact you have 1 single pointer: `p_to_nums` which is used to successively point to different elements of the `nums` array. The type of each `p_to_pointer` is `int*` (pointer to int); not `int**` (pointer to pointer)

Comment: @pmg: Bzzzt.  Wrong answer.  `p_to_pointer` is an array of pointers to ints, so in other words is effectively `int **`.

Comment: @Seth, I meant **each** `p_to_pointer`, that is to say `p_to_pointer[0]` etc... Other than that, the whole array, as you say, has type `int**`. I just find the name misleading (because it is!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sorting *p_to_pointers with sizeof(int) whereas I believe you want to sort p_to_pointers sizeof(int *).

compare_values would need to be adjusted to dereference twice.

If…and this is a big if…I understand what you are trying to do.

Also, your comparison in compare() is needlessly complex.  You can just do a simple subtraction instead of two comparisons and a subtraction.

```
int compare_values (const void *a, const void *b) {
  const int **int_a = (const int **) a;
  const int **int_b = (const int **) b;

  return (**int_b - **int_a);
}

main() {

  int i;
  int nums[5];
  int *p_to_nums;
  int *p_to_pointers[5];

  nums[0] = 4;
  nums[1] = 2;
  nums[2] = 7;
  nums[3] = 4;
  nums[4] = 1;

  p_to_nums = &nums[0];

  for (i=0; i< 5; i++) {
    p_to_pointers[i] = &p_to_nums[i];
    printf("%d p_to_nums: %d p_to_pointers: %u\n", i, (p_to_nums[i]), *p_to_pointers[i]);
  }

  qsort(p_to_pointers, 5, sizeof(int *), compare_values);

  for (i=0; i< 5; i++) {
    printf("%d p_to_nums: %d p_to_pointers: %u\n", i, (p_to_nums[i]), *p_to_pointers[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 p_to_nums: 4 p_to_pointers: 4
1 p_to_nums: 2 p_to_pointers: 2
2 p_to_nums: 7 p_to_pointers: 7
3 p_to_nums: 4 p_to_pointers: 4
4 p_to_nums: 1 p_to_pointers: 1

0 p_to_nums: 4 p_to_pointers: 7
1 p_to_nums: 2 p_to_pointers: 4
2 p_to_nums: 7 p_to_pointers: 4
3 p_to_nums: 4 p_to_pointers: 2
4 p_to_nums: 1 p_to_pointers: 1
```

Comment: Ok, I should have read what you posted while I was writing mine, rather than finishing.  You covered exactly the same ground as I did, including noting the unusual return from the compare function.  +1 to you, and I deleted mine.

Comment: @andrewdski, I suggest undeleting yours; I thought yours had the better explanation. (Which isn't to detract from Seth's explanation in any way -- just that yours spoke better to me. :)

Comment: Ah I wish you hadn't deleted then. :(  The explanation is half the battle with where I'm at right now.  Still trying to understand what this is doing..

Comment: @Jeremy: You are sorting the array of pointers, but you are comparing the integers the pointers point to.  Going too far into pointers to pointers can make my brain hurt, so I usually try to avoid going deeply if I can avoid it.

Comment: I'll undelete it, it may be helpful.  I sometimes see stack overflow as a game (I know, that is *wrong*), and I didn't want to "steal" upvotes from Seth.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `qsort` is `*p_to_pointers`.  That is the same as `p_to_pointers[0]` which you have set to `&p_to_nums[0]`.  That, in turn is the same as `p_to_nums`.  So you call to `qsort` ends up being equivalent to

```
qsort(p_to_nums, 5, sizeof(int), compare_values);
```

Thus, you are sorting `p_to_nums`.

What you want is

```
qsort(p_to_pointers, 5, sizeof(int*), compare_values);
```

Then your compare_values has to convert the `void*` to `int**` rather than `int*`, and you need an extra level of indirection in your dereferences.  The usual way to accomplish the comparison would be something like this:

```
int compare_values (const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int **int_a = a;
    const int **int_b = b;

    return **int_b - **int_a;
}
```

Note that in C the casts from `void*` are not necessary (though in C++ they are).  Also note the more typical subtraction in the `return` statement, rather than your rather unusual construct (though yours works).